# Status of Google Play Services 3.1

Tags: android, google-play-services

Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) says new Google Cloud Messaging API requires Google Play services version 3.1 or higher on the device.

What is the status of implementation of this service?

Are all android devices updated with Google Play services version 3.1 or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Google Play Services are automatically updated on devices via Google Play, the vast majority of devices are running the latest version. It updates whenever the user connects to the internet, without user interaction.

I can't seem to find any statistics on this, but I'm fairly sure that all 2.2 and above devices will be running the latest or penultimate version.